# error ACPI PCC . Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, acpi

After install "ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64" alongside windows7 and restart laptop , I see this message . What Should I Do ?
"Dell Inspiron 5110"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. insert USB that contains installation Ubuntu file
2. restart PC
3. choose Ubuntu
4. push Esc button
5. chose graphic safe option
6. reinstall Ubuntu

   notice : it's delete your Ubuntu volumes data
   I hope that this will be useful .